# Freebase MQL filter where value == null?

Tags: freebase, mql

Can get all triples with value null in specific field?
All people with date_of_birth equal null?

```
[
  "type": "/people/person",  
  "date_of_birth":null,
  "name":null
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use ["optional":"forbidden"](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch03.html#id2955245) directive:

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "date_of_birth": {
    "value":    null,
    "optional": "forbidden"
  },
  "name": null,
  "id":   null
}]​
```

(I added `"id":null` so that the [Query Editor](http://tinyurl.com/lhkalz) gives clickable links)

Note that query has a default `"limit":100,` if you want more results then add an explicit limit clause. If that times out, then you'll need to use a [MQL cursor](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch04.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with lots of results, the undocumented envelope parameter "page" provides more flexibility than "cursor", allowing you to move forward, back, or access a page at random, as opposed to just going forward like you can with the cursor.

The "optional": "forbidden" clause is the key to lots of useful queries.  The "!everything" == "nothing" equivalency is just one of the most common ones.

Tom